# Where can i find Latitude & Longitude data for the coastlines of the world?

Tags: data, latitude-longitude

Im developing an application to print flight paths on a world map.

To do this i need a dataset to describe the latitude and longitude of various coastlines (and country borders if possible) of the world so I can plot them.

Is there anywhere on the web I can find this kind of data? (preferably free/cheap)

Thanks!

Comment: Natural Earth would be the place to go (the data is open source): http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/

Comment: @clairharrison you might be interested in 'Great Circle Mapper' example London Gatwick to Waitangi [Tuuta], Chatham Islands, New Zealand http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=LGW-CHT&R=19143km@LGW credits go to http://www.gcmap.com/credits

Comment: @clairharrison: Done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Natural Earth would be the place to go. The data is open source and generalised for use at different scales.

http://naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors

Answer (score 4):

Check NOAA's [GSHHG](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/shorelines/gshhs.html) (Global Self-consistent, Hierarchical, High-resolution Geography Database).

The database is constantly being updated and maintained (latest update since Im answering this Q: July 1, 2013)

GSHHG is:

> a high-resolution geography data set amalgamated from two data bases
>   in the public domain: World Vector Shorelines (WVS) and CIA World Data
>   Bank II (WDBII). The former is our basis for shorelines while the
>   latter is the basis for lakes, although there are instances where
>   differences in coastline representations necessitated adding WDBII
>   islands to GSHHG. The WDBII source also provides all political borders
>   and rivers. GSHHG data have undergone extensive processing and should
>   be free of internal inconsistencies such as erratic points and
>   crossing segments. The shorelines are constructed entirely from
>   hierarchically arranged closed polygons

The data are available in hdf4/3, ESRI Shapefile and binary formats.

http://www.soest.hawaii.edu/pwessel/gshhg/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Check out https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/ from Jochen Topf. The data has been derived from OpenStreetMap ways tagged with natural=coastline. See also the data update.

Answer (score 1):

GSHHG is definitive your first choice, but depend on the scale you need take also a look at http://www.naturalearthdata.com/

Answer (score 1):

Check Out https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/ for both WSG84 and Mercator Projection.